# Make required checkbox with input name

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a very simple checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="_mc4wp_subscribe_wp-registration-form" value="1">
```

Can't able to make required with jQuery based on just the input name. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hi Aliz and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post your jQuery as well as your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for this, like:

```
$("input[name='_mc4wp_subscribe_wp-registration-form']").prop("required",true);
```